# A subordinate complained behind my back, what are the effective ways to resolve this?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior, people-management

My subordinate went over my head to complain how she isn't growing. She has only has 3 years experience.  She also complained thay she expects some reward like a promotion by now given she is almost 4 years. When in fact she has been promoted twice before my tenure, and for someone with 3-4 years her salary is insanely high.

My boss told me, and frankly I am not only insulted, hurt but sick of this person that it has become a personal issue. It stresses me day in and out. I put a lot of effort into designing challenges for her growth, I was patient with her antics, gave her a famous mentor, gave her leadership space and stepped back, I am very kind to her and yet she still went behind my back.

I have high standards that she doesn't understand because I have experience. She feels her effort is justifiable for a promotion. I told her yes, but it takes time in building your specialty before you manage. Plus we were also building new roles. But not only is she not patient she is immature. I don't trust this person and I am frankly sick of managing her.

My boss is neutral and doesn't want to lose her. 
I sense a power struggle in her towards me and it's uncomfortable. What are effective ways to resolve this issue?

What ways can I ask my boss to not let this happen again?

Comment: I voted to close as unclear what you're asking. We need a clear goal or question to address as a community. Please edit your question with this in mind.

Comment: This seems to come across more as a rant about someone not keeping their head down as opposed to a concrete question. What are you asking for specifically?

Comment: "What ways can I ask my boss to not let this happen again?"  If you are already her manager why would you have to ask your boss about this?

Comment: You should [delete your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) rather than editing the body to be garbage.

Answer (score 3):

1. Talk to your boss about it.   He/she likely realizes this worker has the issues you identified and takes her input with a grain of salt.  Get his/her input on how to handle the situation, explaining what you have told us.
2. Keep in mind there may be a sliver of truth to the feedback she's giving.   I hate to be THAT guy, but I noticed several typos and misspellings in your post. To me, it could indicate some communication issues.  Having said that, I hardly believe it justifies her jumping over you.

Comment: @Nyu huh... ironically, the comment you just made highlights the points made by Joe on a comment. Keith is trying to help you and also being sincere, and you point out that he made a typo on a word? (Which, actually, seems to be ok, and perhaps not meant to be "silver" and trying to reference [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliver_of_Truth)?) ... seems to me that you are in a defensive attitude constantly and perhaps why you are perceiving this as an attack towards you...

Comment: My point exactly @Nyu we are helping you, we are making edits and suggestions to your post, giving answers, one of which mentions that you have some typos. We are not focusing on the typos, but you are... you pointed that out to Keith, when the core topic is regarding this coworker and how to handle the situation... I merely mentioned that you pointing out Keith's "typo" after they pointed out yours could indicate a defensive stance... something I found relevant to point out, as perhaps, you could have the same stance with this coworker and thus why you feel attacked.

Comment: currently working on an answer. I'll stop commenting here as comments are not for that. I am not assuming anything about your character, just pointing out something I perceived, with the hopes that it helps you or sheds some insight on this... I'm sorry if you took it negatively, or if it felt that way. I assure you I am doing this because I want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> What ways can I ask my boss to not let this happen again?

To turn things around a bit, **it would be better if you approached the coworker instead**.

You felt bad when this person "went behind your back", so it is ok for you to express that in a polite way.

Approach them, and tell them such, and that in future situations it would be best if they are clear and told *you* instead, so you can be aware of the situation right there and amend it before the coworker gets frustrated and escalates.

Now, after getting that out of the way, I would ask them *why* they feel they haven't grown or learned, and *what* do they think would be necessary for them to actually grow and learn.

This will actually let you know what this coworker expects or wants, so you can adjust your coaching approach accordingly. You can then see and judge if this coworker's expectations are unreasonable, or if they are really willing to learn or actually are seeking for a power struggle.